# While setting up http to https redirect on Apache (with Drupal and certbot) it broke http access and fails to redirect

Tags: apache, drupal, httpd, certbot

I am trying to set up a Drupal site on a VPS. It was working. I used certbot to set up https, which worked when going to https://example.com . Going to example.com was in http.
I vaguely followed https://linuxize.com/post/redirect-http-to-https-in-apache/ and now it's completely broken.
I can access https://example.com but if I go to example.com it redirects to example.com/https://example.comhttps://example.comhttps://example.com(and keeps going)

I unfortunately did not think to make a backup conf file. I've been running sudo systemctl reload httpd between (saved) conf changes.

I am in /etc/httpd/conf.d and currently have drupal.conf to

'''
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com
ServerAdmin example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal/

```
 Redirect "/" "https://example.com/"

 <Directory /var/www/html/drupal>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

'''

and drupal-le-ssl.conf is set to

'''

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example.com
ServerAdmin example.com

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal/

 <Directory /var/www/html/drupal>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</Directory>
```

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/cycrev.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/cycrev.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

'''

Any suggestions on what I should change to remove that?
I'm not sure if it would be bad for me to post the actual url. It has no content currently, if you think that would be helpful let me know.

Comment: I dont know much about these files, but shouldn't the redirect rule be `Redirect "http://example.com/" "https://example.com/"`

Comment: Hi @RohitGupta, I tried changing the drupal.conf file to that, however it did not change the behavior. I think I set it to what I had because I think that makes any http traffic to any page redirect to the https://example.com site, rather than just to http://example.com .

Comment: I believe I've answered the Q on the redirect ... but apache2.conf uses IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf and certbot creates a .conf in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ so check if your setting are not being overwritten by the one in sites-enabled? it may have broken on last update ... which is why I like to use .htaccess instead of .conf for redirects.